# calculate each table values using if else condition

Tags: jquery, if-statement

i have a table value something like this:

```
sellingprice      result

51                 ?
49                 ?
```

if the sellingprice value is greater than 50 this will be the calculation: **sellingprice - 50 * 0.05 + 3.5**

and if the sellingprice value is less than 50 the calculation will be: **sellingprice * 0.07;**

I am a little bit confused on how to do it in jquery. hope to guide me through this.

Comment: Why are you even calculating this with javascript? Shouldn't it be done on the server side?

Comment: i'm doing it using the client-side calculation

Comment: I understand, but why? It is doesn't require any dynamic changing, why not do it on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var sellingPrice = parseInt($(this).find('.sellingprice').val());

    var result;
    if (sellingPrice > 50) { 
        result = sellingPrice - 50 * 0.05 + 3.5;
    }
    else {
        result = sellingPrice * 0.07;
    }

    $(this).find('.result').val(result);
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/pY9As/2/

Comment: i am going to display the output in the input textbox whose ID is result how to re-write your code?

Comment: If your textbox in the row use `$(this).find('#restult').val(result);` insead of `$(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(result);`. But in this case you will have more then one control with id `result` which is not allowed in html. Use class `result` and appropriate selector: `$(this).find('.result').val(result);`

Comment: sellingprice has an input ID of sellingprice also and result has an input ID of result . I'm a bit confused in  $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(result); This computation is referring to ID's. I understand a bit about your code but still stock and can't display the output.

Comment: Ok, I didn't knew about inputs. Anyway use classes insead of ID's. I've updated sample with classes